# Building OpenCV with CUDA support Error on transpose.cu

Tags: opencv, cuda, compiler-errors

Recently I am trying to build OpenCV with CUDA support, and I met problem while building the module cudaarithm.

**OpenCV source:** git cloned from : http://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

**OpenCV branch:** master branch

**OpenCV commit:**

```
`commit 5466e321b8c8f97536002a357e5b7ff49a5d2bf9, on Tue Feb 10 12:17:11 2015 +0000`
```

**CUDA version:** CUDA 6.5

**Hardware:** MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)

**GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

**OS Version:** OS X Yosemite

**Steps I used:**

```
1. cd in OpenCVSource, then mkdir myrelease, and cd myrelease

2. cmake -DPLANTUML_JAR=/usr/local/Cellar/plantuml/8002  -D BUILD_DOCS=1 -DPYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib -DPYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/libpython3.4m.dylib -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -Wno-dev -DNVCC_FLAGS_EXTRA="-Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++; -Xlinker -stdlib=libstdc++" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS=" -stdlib=libstdc++" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++" ..

3. make  VERBOSE=1
```

**Expect Result:** Building success without error

**Actual Result:** when building OpenCVSource/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/transpose.cu, error happend like below:

```
/Users/Hawk/Documents/study/DIP/OpenCV/OpenCVSource/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/transpose.cu(61): *error: identifier "getInputMat" is undefined*

/Users/Hawk/Documents/study/DIP/OpenCV/OpenCVSource/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/transpose.cu(67): *error: identifier "getOutputMat" is undefined*

/Users/Hawk/Documents/study/DIP/OpenCV/OpenCVSource/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/transpose.cu(92): *error: identifier "syncOutput" is undefined*
```

**Then what action I take:**

1. check the code and I found these undefined symboles are defined in OpenCVSource/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp
2. check the code and I confrim that the "transpose.cu" file include "opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp"
3. check the building log, and I the confirm the private.cuda.hpp is in the search path of header file
4. cp "opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp" as another file "opencv2/core/hawk.hpp", and then edit "transpose.cu" to include this new file, and I found
   the "undifined symbole error" disapeared.

Although this is a workable workaround, I would like know whether the original OpenCV source cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

All, I think I found the problem cause.

Before I met such problem, I've already build and install OpenCV using older code from the git repo. So that there already have header files in my /usr/local/include/opencv2, especially there is **/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp**.

However, it is an older one that doesn't define the symbols reporting undefined in above question. At the same time I found during the building nvcc have -I/usr/local/include in the command line, so that it use wrong **private.cuda.hpp**. As you know it should use the one in OpenCVSource, not the older installed one.

I think the solution is to gracefully remove the original installed OpenCV from my computer, then build again. I am trying and I will report later.